# Does Identify tool of ArcGIS Desktop have Python script behind it?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, identify

Is there a Python script for "Identify" tool in ArcMap 10?

I need to create a customized script tool for that and add it to a toolbar.

The attribute table of my feature class has many fields. Out of that the custom identify tool should display the values of only two fields. i need to add that as a button in my tool bar.. when the user clicks any feature, the values of the two fields should be displayed.

Answer (score 12):

If the intent of your application is to provide the user a simplified view when identifying features then I would suggest just turn off all the other fields within the layer properties that you do not want to show.  When the user identifies a feature, they will only see info for the two that are turned on.  This can be done by:

1. Right click layer in the ArcMap TOC and select Properties
2. Select Fields tab
3. Select Turn All Fields off icon
4. Then manually turn on the two fields you want to show info for
5. Now, just save your map document with these preferences, and give it to your user(s).

This should save you time in re-creating this tool.

Comment: Additionally, within an MXD you can create a custom Display Expression from the Display tab of a layer's Layer Properties window. For example, I use the expression `[PROJ_ID] & " : " & [PROJ_YEAR]` to display the values of those two attributes, separated by a colon, in the Identity window (rather than just letting ArcMap pick whatever field it somehow judges to be the best).

Answer (score 1):

The Identify tool does not have a Python script behind it.  If you can provide more details of what you are trying to achieve, and if you are using ArcGIS 10.1, then a Python Add-in may be an option to build a simplified "Identify" tool.

I recommend starting with the [online help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_Python_add_in/014p00000025000000/).  It is a Tool that you create, and you will probably ask for user input of a single point, before using that to select feature(s), open a SearchCursor and populate a [MessageBox](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000021000000) with the results.

Comment: Late to the party here buuuut.. Maybe the OP is obliquely referencing the fact that the Identify Tool returns results from a related table, a thoroughly manual process - one click at a time, and it sure would be handy to be able to script the query as a loop and write the return out to (e.g.) a CSV file. -- People have been asking for some version of that functionality for two decades at least. Obviously ArcGIS can do this thing but how to automate it with a script is a mystery.